# Split website link into 2 href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, href

On my website public: http://abv.mk/company.aspx?id=40056 , i want to split http://www.donholding.com.mk & http://www.webklinika.mk to be separate links (and separate clickable like two different links - hrefs).

But in my admin-panel for the field website i only have 1 field available, where i input 2 web site links splited with ","

So is it possible in the public asp-file "company.aspx", to edit the file and insert some Javascript code, so i split the link from 1 href to 2 hrefs ?

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblComWeb"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.donholding.com.mk, www.webklinika.mk" title="">www.donholding.com.mk, www.webklinika.mk</a> | <a href="mailto:donholding@live.com" title="">donholding@live.com</a></span>
```

Comment: We're going to have to see some code to see what you are currently trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to understand what you mean....

Comment: On second look this could just be spams.

Comment: It is not spam, I guess. If you go to the first link he provided, next to some e-mail address there will be two different websites, but they are in the same `a` html tag. He wants to know if it is possible to change them into two clickable links, as in the way he made it, they are only visible, but clicking on it will lead to a URL which doesn't makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have one field in the DB which stores the URL. This should probably instead be its own table - company_url, which takes company_id (in thie case, 40056) and the URL. You should bring back a DataSet, and create a HTML string to put in to the Literal (or whatever you're using).

That's the "you should do this" answer.

Now.. you *could* do...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $('span[id$="lblComWeb"]');
    var el_a = el.children('a');
    links = el_a.html();
    links = links.split(',');
    el.html('');
    $.each(links,function(l){
        var e = '<a href="http://'+$.trim(links[l])+'" title="'+el.attr('title')+'" target="_blank">'+links[l]+'</a>'; 
        el.append((l > 0 ? ',' : '') + e); 
    });
});
```

as you're already using jQuery. However, it's cheap and dirty and nasty and yucky.
Just putting that snippet in to your company.aspx file (between some  tags) should do the trick.

Comment: Okey awsome, now it works links are splited, but the e-mail is not visible now :)
http://abv.mk/company.aspx?id=40056

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise email was part of the same span - it shouldn't be! You'll just need to save that email text to a var before you do "links = el.html('');", and el.append() it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This page only allows you to display one website.

The `href` property of the `a` html tag only support reference to one address/page.

What you could do is put there the link to another page which is yours, and in this page you can put as many different links to anywhere you want and other information too. Maybe search for some URL shortener service which allows something like this.

Now, if you actually do have access to the source code and modify it, all you have to do is:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblComWeb">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.donholding.com.mk" >www.donholding.com.mk</a>, <a target="_blank" href="www.webklinika.mk" >www.webklinika.mk</a> | <a href="mailto:donholding@live.com" title="">donholding@live.com</a>
</span>
```